# What type of security does Gazzang zNcrypt provide?

Tags: encryption, databases

We have just planned to implement the same in our organization, and I believe this will encrypt files and data on disk. I have two questions:

1. Does it provide column level encryption in database (if I want to encrypt sensitive data like CVV, account, pin in database whereas allow other fields to be read)?
2. We already have KMS (HSM) which can encrypt the data on files using tokenisation, so why go for zNcrypt?

Comment: Related: [What does Gazzang zNcrypt actually protect against?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47953/what-does-gazzang-zncrypt-actually-protect-against)

Comment: Related: Gazzang architect in this question: [How to improve performance of encrypted MySQL database on Linux backend server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11683/how-to-improve-performance-of-encrypted-mysql-database-on-linux-backend-server/11994#11994)